Can an IP rated seal be made with a magnetically attached lid?
I am exploring the idea of a device (think internet router which needs to be possible to install outside) with an IP rated sealing panel. I would like it to be easy to remove the lid, and ideally tool-less. It should also be IP54 minimum but ideally IP65. Can this be achieved?

Of course it can be achieved with magnets involved (e.g. look at Magswitches), but whether it is the best way is doubtful. Other tool-less mechanisms (e.g. as used by lock-n-lock tupperwares, or ammo cans) would likely be more appropriate?

If a 1500 psi water jet can't pry it open, how are my fingers going to do that? Wing nut cam locks with various IP ratings are available and pretty cheap.

I don't like the failure mode. It would work perfectly until it failed totally and you lost the lid. I'd prefer something with a more progressive failure. I'm also not a fan of the wingnut camlocks. They have ones that are low profile and use a wrench.

IP54's approved for open deck use on vessels. As a general note it's often better to allow for some controlled water ingress and provide a drain path than to make it perfectly sealed.

@PhilSweet Looking up the definitions of IP codes, IPx5 doesn't seem to require anything close to 1500PSI.
